# JQ to search for a regex

Tags: json, curl, jq

I have the below JSON from the curl output and I need to retrieve the number of `host_name` (hosts) that has `wkn` in its hostname. In the below json we have two hosts that has `wkn` in their `host_name`.

```
{
  "href": "http://10.10.0.10:8080",
  "Hosts": {
    "cluster_name": "test",
    "host_name": "testmasternode.example.test.com",
    "ip": "10.10.0.10"
  }
}
{
  "href": "http://10.10.0.10:8080",
  "Hosts": {
    "cluster_name": "test",
    "host_name": "testwkn01.example.test.com",
    "ip": "10.10.0.11"
  }
}
{
  "href": "http://10.10.0.10:8080",
  "Hosts": {
    "cluster_name": "test",
    "host_name": "testwkn02.example.test.com",
    "ip": "10.10.0.12"
  }
}
```

I tried a couple of ways

1. This doesn't give any output

```sh
curl -sH http://10.10.0.10:8080/api/v1/clusters/test/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip \
| jq -r '.items | .[] | select(.Hosts.host_name == ("*wkn01.*"))'
```

2. This gives an error

```sh
curl -sH http://10.10.0.10:8080/api/v1/clusters/test/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip  \
| jq -r '.items | .[] | select(.Hosts.host_name | match("*wkn01.*"))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:76): Regex failure: target of repeat operator is not specified
```

Comment: `*wkn01.*` is not a valid regex. The first `*` needs specification what to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `test` instead of `match` as you only need a boolean result. Then, to test if any item "has `wkn` in their `host_name`" the regex `wkn` should suffice. Lastly, as you "need to retrieve the number of `host_name`", simply finalize with `length` (which needs an array, therefore I also changed `.[]` to `map`).

```sh
... | jq -r '.items | map(select(.Hosts.host_name | test("wkn"))) | length'
2
```

Comment: Thanks, @pmf. it worked